# Python subprocess execute on remote machines?

Tags: linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I have to write a script to get information from remote hosts, Such and kernel version, df -h, uptime etc.. So How to use function to execute on remote side, or are there any other way to do it. Sample code as below, Appreciate if someone could help me on this.

```
def GetKernel():
        krnl=platform.release()
        print(krnl)


def SSHserver(server):
        sshProcess = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", server, GetKernel()],
                       shell=False,
                       stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                       stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        sshProcess.stdin.write(MountPointChecker())
        print(sshProcess)

SSHserver('192.168.10.123')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Fabric**.

Firt install the fabric package, in Debian 8 :

```
apt install fabric
```

Create a file named **fabfile.py**, content here :

```
#!/usb/bin/env python2
# File fabfile.py
from fabric.api import run

def host_type():
  run('uname -s')

def host_kernel():
  run('uname -r')

def host_kernel_release_name_df():
  run('uname -r')
  run('lsb_release -ds')
  run('hostname')
  run('df -TPh')
```

Now to execute in remote server :

```
fab -H user@server1,user@server2 host_kernel_release_name_df
```

You can run multiple def :

```
fab -H user@server1,user@server2 host_type host_kernel
```

Fabric Website : http://www.fabfile.org/

Other SSH command in Python :
https://wiki.python.org/moin/SecureShell

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Im unable to install any software or tools in the linux servers. So i have to use default modules and python 2.6 version.

Comment: Do you really need to script in python ?
Because without plugin is hard.
Else you can try in pure bash.

Comment: Thanks friend, Yes i understand this is little bit difficult